# insert linq query in many to many relation in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-query-syntax

Hi guys I am facing a problem in asp.net mvc.

I have two tables `Users` and `Projects` and third table which creates a many to many relation in them `User_Project` but when I imported the tables in visual studio there is no table of `User_Project` but I can access there values from navigation or like `db.Users.Where(u => u.Projects.Contains(SomeUser));`.

But now I just want to add the `User` in database who is related to some project and I am using following query but its not working.

```
Project pro = db.Projects.Where(p => p.ID == x).FirstOrDefault();
                        pro.Users.Add(usr);
                        db.Users.Add(usr);
          error line => db.SaveChanges();
```

Hope i explained my problem.

> Unable to update the EntitySet 'User_Project' because it has a
>   DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the
>    element to support the current
>   operation.

I also have the primary keys in both tables `Users.ID` and `Projects.ID` and also the link in edmx file.

```
<AssociationConnector Association="BugMesh_Model.User_Project" ManuallyRouted="false" />
```

UserModel

```
    public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Bugs = new HashSet<Bug>();
        this.Bugs1 = new HashSet<Bug>();
        this.Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bug> Bugs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bug> Bugs1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Project Model

```
    public partial class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        this.Bugs = new HashSet<Bug>();
        this.Components = new HashSet<Component>();
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bug> Bugs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Component> Components { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Any help @teovankot

Comment: Show your full model, looks like mistake somewhere in your model declaration

Comment: @teovankot these are the model classes of users and projects
i am new in asp.net mvc kindly help me out thankyou!

Comment: Are you using code first?

Comment: No database First approach these all model classes are generated by EF

Comment: Can you show your usr object declaration and check foreign keys in you db. Regenerate model

Comment: Yes i have foreign keys in my User_Project table but m sorry i dnt know where is user decelaration????

Comment: How could that be?

Comment: i can send u snap shots but in email only?

Comment: Any one Help Please ?????????

Answer (score 0):

you add user 2 time because it's reference type  to the same location in memory

you can do that

```
      pro.Users.Add(usr);
      db.SaveChanges();
```

and please check if the user table has  `primary key`